# Jasper report, subreport, and encoding

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, jasper-reports, subreport

I have a report and a subreport with a resource bundle for french internationalisation. No error nor warning are thrown, but when I use this report to create a pdf, weird char appears, because of an encoding mistake (Ã© for é is an example).

I am still investigating on that issue, but I guess it is subreport related.

Several precisions:

- I do not know why, but the properties files are utf8 encoded, and the reader of the resource bundle is overriden (and I am not allowed to change that :( ).
- the special character look fine in the main report; the problem only occurs in the subreport section. (and everything come from the same property file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok problem solved:

In the java file, after overriding whatever needed on the resourcebundle (for me: UTF-8 as input encoding), you do:

```
reportParamMap.put(JRParameter.REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE, resourceBundle);
```

Well, in the JRXML file, do NOT forget to pass the resource bundle to the subreports that need it:

```
<subreport>

    <reportElement />

    <subreportParameter name="REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE">
        <subreportParameterExpression>
            <![CDATA[$P{REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE}]]>
        </subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>

    <dataSourceExpression/>

    <subreportExpression/>

</subreport>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your properties file, have you tried using the code for the character/special characters?

For example the character "`é`" must be `\u00E9`

Comment: Yes that method works, but the fat is, it means the property file is now ANSI encoded, and the special character are represented by escaped unicode sequence...

I have to resolve that problem with only one charset: UTF-8